# how to unlink /var/cache/apt/archives/partial

Tags: command-line, apt

I tried to do `sudo apt-get upgrade` and in result it asked me for extra space, as in searches to this i found below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulJME.png) commands in ask a question, which is

> With this method you re-route the location where .debs are stored:
>
> ```
> sudo mv -i /var/cache/apt /media/{dir_of_mounted_disc}
> sudo ln -s /media/{dir_of_mounted_disc}/apt /var/cache/apt
> ```
>
> Run the upgrade and install. After you are done you can switch back to
> normal with:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get clean
> sudo unlink /var/cache/apt
> sudo mv /media/{dir_of_mounted_disc}/apt /var/cache
> ```
>
> Of course {dir_of_mounted_disc} needs to be changed to the name of
> your mounted disc.

Now I'm trying to do `sudo apt-get upgrade` and is followed with this error:

```
─$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmpdec3 libnginx-mod-http-geoip libnginx-mod-http-image-filter
  libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream
  libnginx-mod-stream-geoip libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev libpython3.10-minimal
  libpython3.10-stdlib nginx-common nginx-core python3-speaklater python3.10
  python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
E: Archives directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)
```

How do i resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

The error message just said that the directory `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial` is missing

You could just do this in a terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
```

update your package list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you upgrade

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```